# Getting Error 91 when parsing HTML data using the MSXML2.XMLHTTP60 object

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, web-scraping

I'm using the `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` object to connect to a website, grab the HTML and parse it for relevent data. Essentially, this is a web crawler.

After the 10th or so entry, I get a 91 error. Meaning that the data is not present in the object. I end the program and then, when I restart, I recieve this error in another spot that previousely worked. I can't seem to get past it. I later found out that this second 91 error can be "solved" by restarting the Excel.

Now, for the first 91 error, I found that when I step through my program, everything works. I then added in a delay after so many loops. The delay is about 3 seconds near the spot of the first 91 error. This seems to solve it.

I don't quite understand, why would this delay be so critical? I would like to remove this delay and have the program operate at max speed. Unless it is absolutely necessary due to some glich. I don't think that I should need a delay in order to get the function to work properly.

Here is the complete code; the spots where the error occurs are marked.

```
Option Explicit

Public baseLink As String
Public baseRow As String
Public basePageNav As String
Public rowNumber As Integer
Public someCounter As Integer
Public masterBrowser As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60


Sub Initialization()
    baseLink = "https://www.fbo.gov/index.php"
    baseRow = "row_"
    basePageNav = "?s=opportunity&mode=list&tab=list&pageID="
    rowNumber = 2
    someCounter = 1
End Sub


Sub extractData(URLLink As String)
   ' Dim httpAddress As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim cResponse As String
   ' Set HTMLdoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Dim HTMLdoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim testString As String
    Dim closePos As Integer

    Dim titleString As String
    Dim solicitationNumber As String
    Dim agencyName As String
    Dim officeName As String
    Dim locationName As String
    Dim postedDate As String
    Dim responseDate As String
    Dim noticeString As String
    Dim classificationCode As String
    Dim NAICScode As String

    Dim temp As String

    With masterBrowser
        .Open "GET", URLLink, False
        .send
    End With

    With masterBrowser
        While Not .readyState = 4
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        Wend

        While Not .Status = 200
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        Wend

        cResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    ' For some reason, there is a bug in the library. If the applciation runs
    ' too fast, then the program will eventually recieve a 91 error.
    ' This if statement will cause the program to delay by 3 secs every 9th
    ' entry in order to prevent the 91 error from appearing

'    If someCounter = 9 Then
 '       Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
  '      someCounter = 1
   ' Else
    '    someCounter = someCounter + 1
    'End If

   ' cResponse = StrConv(httpAddress.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    cResponse = Mid$(cResponse, InStr(1, cResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    With HTMLdoc
        .body.innerHTML = cResponse

        If .getElementsByClassName("agency-header")(0) Is Nothing Then 'If this is empty, then this will cause the first 91 error
            MsgBox ("It is empty")

            ' So, lets try another reconnect?

            Dim anotherAttemptB As String

            With masterBrowser
                .Open "GET", URLLink, False
                .send
                anotherAttemptB = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
            End With

            anotherAttemptB = Mid$(anotherAttemptB, InStr(1, anotherAttemptB, "<!DOCTYPE "))
            .body.innerHTML = anotherAttemptB
            closePos = InStr(.getElementsByClassName("agency-header")(0).innerHTML, "/") ' 91 error caused here
        Else
            closePos = InStr(.getElementsByClassName("agency-header")(0).innerHTML, "/")
        End If

        titleString = Mid(.getElementsByClassName("agency-header")(0).innerHTML, 1, closePos)
        titleString = Replace(titleString, "<H2>", "")
        titleString = Replace(titleString, "</", "")

        testString = .getElementsByClassName("sol-num")(0).innerHTML
        solicitationNumber = Replace(.getElementsByClassName("sol-num")(0).innerHTML, "Solicitation Number: ", "")

        testString = .getElementsByClassName("agency-name")(0).innerHTML

        agencyName = Split(.getElementsByClassName("agency-name")(0).innerHTML, "<BR>")(0)
        agencyName = Replace(agencyName, "Agency: ", "")

        officeName = Split(.getElementsByClassName("agency-name")(0).innerHTML, "<BR>")(1)
        officeName = Replace(officeName, "Office: ", "")

        locationName = Split(.getElementsByClassName("agency-name")(0).innerHTML, "<BR>")(2)
        locationName = Replace(locationName, "Location: ", "")

        postedDate = .getElementById("dnf_class_values_procurement_notice__posted_date__widget").innerHTML

        responseDate = .getElementById("dnf_class_values_procurement_notice__response_deadline__widget").innerHTML
        responseDate = Replace(responseDate, "&nbsp;", " ")

        noticeString = .getElementById("dnf_class_values_procurement_notice__procurement_type__widget").innerHTML
        classificationCode = .getElementById("dnf_class_values_procurement_notice__classification_code__widget").innerHTML

        NAICScode = .getElementById("dnf_class_values_procurement_notice__naics_code__widget").innerHTML
        closePos = InStr(NAICScode, " ")
        NAICScode = Mid(NAICScode, 1, closePos)
    End With

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rowNumber).Value = titleString
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & rowNumber).Value = solicitationNumber
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & rowNumber).Value = agencyName
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & rowNumber).Value = officeName
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & rowNumber).Value = locationName
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & rowNumber).Value = postedDate
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & rowNumber).Value = responseDate
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & rowNumber).Value = noticeString
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & rowNumber).Value = classificationCode
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & rowNumber).Value = NAICScode
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & rowNumber).Value = URLLink

    rowNumber = rowNumber + 1

    Set HTMLdoc = Nothing

End Sub

Sub test()
    Initialization

    Dim linkArray(19) As String
    Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim myUrl As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sResponse As String
    'Set HTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Dim HTML As New HTMLDocument

    Dim testStrin As String

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Title:"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = "Solicitation #:"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value = "Agency:"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value = "Office:"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1").Value = "Location:"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value = "Posted On:"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G1").Value = "Response Date:"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H1").Value = "Notice Type:"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I1").Value = "Classification Code:"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J1").Value = "NAICS Code:"
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K1").Value = "Link:"

    myUrl = baseLink & basePageNav & "1"

    With masterBrowser
        .Open "GET", myUrl, False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

'    sResponse = StrConv(xmlhttp.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    With HTML
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse

        For i = 0 To 19
            Dim linkString As String
            Dim openPos As Integer
            Dim closePos As Integer

            If HTML.getElementById(baseRow & CStr(i)) Is Nothing Then ' To make matters even more confusing, after the first 91 error, here is the second until you restart excel
                MsgBox ("It is also empty")
                Dim anotherAttempt As String

                With masterBrowser
                    .Open "GET", myUrl, False
                    .send
                    anotherAttempt = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
                End With

                anotherAttempt = Mid$(anotherAttempt, InStr(1, anotherAttempt, "<!DOCTYPE "))

                .body.innerHTML = anotherAttempt

                linkString = .getElementById(baseRow & CStr(i)).Children(0).innerHTML
            Else
                linkString = .getElementById(baseRow & CStr(i)).Children(0).innerHTML
            End If

            openPos = InStr(linkString, "?")
            closePos = InStr(linkString, "w") + 3

            linkString = Mid(linkString, openPos, closePos - openPos)
            linkString = Replace(linkString, "amp;", "")
            linkString = baseLink & linkString

            linkArray(i) = linkString
        Next i
    End With



    For i = 0 To 19
        extractData (linkArray(i))
    Next i

    Set HTML = Nothing

    MsgBox ("Finished")

End Sub
```

As requested by QHarr, the response text from when the first time 91 error occurs is as follows:

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

And the response text for when the second 91 error occurs:

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

And the response text before the 91 error:

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: What's the text of the error? Which line (or type of command) is generating the error?

Comment: Just as a guess: there is always some delay, waiting for a web-page to respond. That's why software that interacts with the Internet uses asynchronous processing. VBA runs synchronously, not async. Something may be timing out, which is why a delay may be helping.

Comment: ^ @CindyMeister's comment is an important one.You may also be being blocked/throttled for rapid access. Have you examined the content of what is in the xmlhttp response when error 91 occurs? Adding a delay after x loops is a common and useful technique, though you have to tweak to optimize this step in terms of number of revolutions to wait before introducing and length of wait.

Comment: @CindyMeister I was thinking that, and it does make sense. However, when opening a connection for XMLHTTP, you have `xmlhttp.Open Method, URL, async(true or false)` The async parameter for me is set to False so I assume this is running synchronously. If you look in my code, I also do have a block that will wait until the XMLHTTP is ready (ReadyState = 4) and the status is finished. I still receive the 91 error

Comment: @CindyMeister Also, I do have the lines marked with a comment on where the 91 error.

Comment: @Qharr that is a good point. However, the OP has pointed out that the program can only recover from the 91 error once excel restarts. So his would that "fix" the 91 error? Why not wait 5+ minutes? I am assuming the op still gets this error after waiting a long time.

Comment: @philm The OP states a delay at intervals within looping can remove the 91 error. Restarting just shifts when in the loop (I believe) the 91 error occurs. If I were the OP I would add in a test sub which logs out to txt file the actual response and have that triggered by error handling (example On Error GoTo ErrHand ....... ErrHand: Select Case err.number : Case 91 ....) I would then inspect that file to see what I could clean about what is happening. Simply stating an item is not present is not sufficient to effectively tailor a solution.

Comment: @QHarr Looking through the code, I think that he might have something similar. There is this line: `If .getElementsByClassName("agency-header")(0) Is Nothing Then` which when true would indicate that the data in the HTML document object is either empty or incomplete. I also did run the code that the OP posted and after an initial 91 error, I would also get additional 91 errors even after the program restarted executing. So I think that there is some sort of connection blocking happening?

Comment: @philm  What did the actual response text look like for the 91 error?

Comment: Updated with QHarr requests of the response text